# What's the correct structure for 'enable-background' of the SVG element?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, svg, definitelytyped

I use React w/ Typescript, using the "DefinitelyTyped" definitions.
I've recently upgraded from React v16.0.0 to v16.3.0, using the v16.3.9 React types (`@types/react`).

I used to have my SVG element looking like this, with `enable-background` as a style attribute:

```
import * as React from "react"

export class CaretSvgRight
extends React.PureComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGElement>, object> {

  render(){
    return <svg 
      style={{"enable-background":"new 0 0 292.359 292.359"}}
      {...this.props}            
    >
      <path d="..."/>
    </svg>
  }
}
```

With the new typings, I had to change to the weird looking `SVGSVGElement` type for the target of the SVGProps type and that required me to move the `enable-background` attribute onto the `SVG` level:

```
import * as React from "react"

export class CaretSvgRight
extends React.PureComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>, object> {

  render(){
    return <svg 
      enableBackground="new 0 0 292.359 292.359"
      {...this.props}            
    >
      <path d="..."/>
    </svg>
  }
}
```

Does that look right, or am I supposed to do something different to get the `enable-background` attribute back into the style attributes (were the typings wrong before and this attribute is supposed to be on the `SVG` element, or are they wrong now?)

It seems to make no difference at all to how the SVG looks in the browser any way (tested in Chrome) - should I just delete the whole `enable-background` thing and not worry about it?